# Horizontal scrolling text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

Can anyone provide any tips when it comes to implementing some text that scrolls horizontally?
Right now I have a `ScrollView *scrollView` with a `UILabel *textLabel` inside of it.

I have the position of the label changing within the view until it is outside the bounds of the screen. The label is then reset to its original position and it starts scrolling again.

The problem(s) I am having are when I say: `[textLabel sizeToFit];`
This takes away the labels ability to handle multiple lines of text because once I say `[textLabel sizeToFit];` it changes it into one big string.

Is there a simpler way to achieve the desired effect?

ANY help is greatly appreciated

P.S. The text inside of the label will be parsed from a website... so the size/length of the string will not be consistant.

Comment: I'd try a UILabel inside a UIView with clipsToBounds set to YES, and animating via Core Animation.

Comment: I think I may have wasted everyone's time...
I just finished watching the Stanford lecture on Table Views and I think I can achieve the desired result using such...

Does anyone think this is the appropriate way to go? Im not looking to do too much animation with the text, I only want the auto scrolling effect with some nice font, colors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(widthOfLabel, 9999);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [@"Text" sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

then you can use `expectedLabelSize.height` or `expectedLabelSize.width` and change the frame size of `UILabel`